# What does this fish market banner say?

Tags: hiragana, calligraphy, writing-identification, hentaigana

A friend has at home this banner from an old fish shop in Sapporo. I suppose it's a souvenir from Japan. It intrigues me a lot!

What's this の with an upper stroke and the ten-ten? What's the name for the place? Does the following make sense: ⻌の魚? On the bottom left there's a phone number written with kanji?

Maybe this is the result of the (free)style of the calligrapher or the の with the stroke and ten-ten is to resemble a fish?

[image: 本の魚]

Comment: This is a complete guess, but I might say しじの, where the stroke+ten ten above the の is a stylistic/sideways hiragana voiced くりかえし mark　(ゞ).  Thus, the じ after a し.  No basis for this really though.

Comment: If it is a hentaigana then the の with a 点 and the 濁点 should read が but  I have no clue for the first.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think it's read right-to-left as [魚{うお}がし 'fish market'](http://www.excite.co.jp/world/j_dictionary/ITEM-DJR_uogasi_-010/%E3%81%86%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E9%AD%9A%E3%80%8A%E6%B2%B3%E5%B2%B8%E3%80%8B/?itemid=DJR_uogasi_-010&title=%E3%81%86%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E9%AD%9A%E3%80%8A%E6%B2%B3%E5%B2%B8%E3%80%8B).  The kana が and し are written as [hentaigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hentaigana), variant forms of kana that are usually no longer used.

This is が:

[image: hentaigana が]

This is し:

[image: hentaigana し]

(Images taken from [benricho.org](http://www.benricho.org/kana/))

Comment: 皆さん、ありがとう！ I've learned lots with istrasci-san guess and snailplane-san answer which I presume it's correct. :)